Не зкпускается машина в virtualbox
Я в начале сентября еще установил себе убунту на виртуалку. Она работала, все хорошо, но вчера я запустил машину, и у меня просто чёрный экран (квадратик)  и ничего нет, даже значка virtualbox нет. И вот вопрос что делать и почему так?

Что я перепробовал:

Установил заново и virtualbox и Ubuntu
Увеличил количество памяти оперативной 8 гб, постоянной 32 гб и видео 128 мб
Выключил и снова включил в bios svm mode
Включал 3д ускорение
Проверил включён ли nested paging


@HolyBlackCat я переустанавливал и virtualbox и ubuntu

Пардон, не заметил.

Правый Ctrl+R чё делает?

Сетевуха - нат или сетевой мост?

@don Rumata я нат поставил

@don Rumata проблема в компьютере. У меня даже в других визуалках такое. В итоге я себе wsl поставил
